# How to pip install a celery task module

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a django REST API setup on one machine (currently in test on local machine but will be on a web server eventually). Let's call this machine "client". I also have a computing server to run CPU-intensive tasks that requires a long execution time. Let's call this machine "run-server".

"run-server" runs a celery worker connected to a local rabbitmq server. The worker currently is in a git module with this structure:

```
proj/
    client.py
    cmd.sh
    requirements.txt
    tasks.py
```

The whole thing runs in a virtualenv for what it's worth. The `cmd.sh` basically executes `celery multi start workername -A tasks -l info` on "run-server". The `client.py` is a cli script that can submit a tasks to the "run-server" manually from the shell from any machine (i.e. the "client").

I want to run the equivalent of the client script from a django setup *without* having to copy the `tasks.py` and `client.py` code in the django repository. Ideally I would `pip install proj` from the django code and import proj to use it just like the client script does.

***How can I package proj to achieve that?***

I am used to package my own python module with a structure roughly looking like:

```
proj/
    bin/
        proj
    proj/
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
        script.py
    setup.py
    requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work on my own. The structure above just works. Instead of `celery multi start workername -A tasks -l info`, you simply replace with `celery multi start workername -A proj.tasks -l info` and everything works. The same version of the module have to be installed within django and as the worker because the job queuein is done via duck-typing (i.e. the path and names must match)